# Send BOTH Parameters and Body Content with PHP POST cURL

Tags: php, curl

I need to send **both** key value pair parameters **and** HTTP body content (in this case, an XML string) using PHP. cURL is my go to method for similar tasks, but I can't figure out how to send both with a single cURL Post request.

I can use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to send an array of key value pairs:

`curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('foo' => 'bar', 'fruit' = 'orange));`

**OR** I can use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to send an XML string.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);
```

The API docs require both request parameters and a body in the single post request. This API also throttles requests so I'm limited in my debug attempts per hour. Please help.

Edit: API Docs (see examples at bottom): http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html

Comment: Are you sure it's not request parameters (i.e. POSTFIELDS) plus some headers?

Comment: You are giving too few information for us to help. please improve the question with more information (like what api you use). Also, why not put the $xml in the query with the key 'body'.

Comment: Basically: not possible. In HTTP, the key-value pairs are transmitted in the body of the request. So you cannot send a custom body *and* key-value pairs. I'd suggest sending the XML string as a separate key-value pair: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('foo' => 'bar', 'fruit' => 'orange', 'xmlstring' => $xml));`

Comment: You can still put request parameters in the URL of a POST: `$curl = curl_init('http://url.com?foo=bar');`

Comment: @rickdenhaan Sort of the conclusion I reached as well 'not possible'.  The API is looking for the $xml as the HTTP body so it wouldn't read from the 'xmlstring' (or any other made up) key param if I put it there.

Answer (score 2):

you have 3 places you can put data, the URL itself (which is technically not part of the headers, this is where php gets the $_GET data from), the headers (php put this in the $_SERVER variable), and the post body.

you must choose which of these 3 places you want to put your data. most likely, what you want, is to put `array('foo' => 'bar', 'fruit' = 'orange')`  in the GET url, to do that, do: `$url='http://example.com?'.http_build_query(array('foo' => 'bar', 'fruit' = 'orange'));`

- but if you really want to send both the POST parameters, and the XML in the http request body, which is probably not what you want, but if you're really sure, it would be: `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query(array('foo' => 'bar', 'fruit' = 'orange').$xml);` - aka, concatenate the strings. but this will result in an invalid XML file, and is probably not what you want.
- if you want to put the data in the headers, use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, but make sure its formatted as `keyname` then `:` then a space then the value, but there's lots of bytes that are illegal for headers, off the top of my head, \r\n<>\x00 - but there's more too.